# Woocommerce specific price changing

Tags: woocommerce

I have a problem with Woo-commerce and i think i m pretty close to find solution,
but have a bug :

My task is to make changes to woocommerce product default prices based on : username , specific product id and product category .

code is here :

```
`if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','change_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_get_regular_price','change_price', 10, 2); 
add_filter('woocommerce_get_sale_price','change_price', 10, 2);
}

function change_price($price, $productd){
    $vrednost=$productd->get_sku( );
       $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); //uzimam trenutno logovanog korisnika
            global $wpdb;
            global $mydb;
            global $cena;
            $cena=$productd->price;
            $mydb= new wpdb('root','','wordpress123','localhost'); 
            $mydb->show_errors(); 
            $userna=$current_user->user_login;  
            $paypal_id = $mydb->get_results("select sifra_kupca from wp_prodajno_mjesto WHERE user ='$userna'");
              foreach ($paypal_id as $objs) {
              $sifrovani=$objs->sifra_kupca; 
              }
            $standard_rabat=$mydb->get_results("select standardni_rabat from wp_kupac WHERE sifra_kupca ='$sifrovani'");
              foreach ($standard_rabat as $objs) {
              $ispis=$objs->standardni_rabat;
              }
            $konacnorabat=$ispis;
            $price =intval($productd->price)-((intval($ispis)/100)*$productd->price); 
            $ima=$mydb->get_results("select sifra_kupca from wp_cjenik_kupca WHERE sifra_kupca ='$sifrovani'");       
            foreach ($ima as $objs) {
              $ispis7=$objs->sifra_kupca;
              }
            if ($ispis7==NULL)
            {
             return $price;
             exit;
            }
            $grupa=$mydb->get_results("select grupa_artikala from wp_cjenik_kupca WHERE sifra_kupca ='$sifrovani'");
            foreach ($grupa as $objs) {
              $ispis4=$objs->grupa_artikala;
              }
            if (!($ispis4==NULL))
           {
            global $post;
            $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',);
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID,'product_cat', $args);
            $count = count($terms); 
            if ($count > 0) {
              foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $cata=$term->name;
              }
            }
           $sifbaza=$productd->get_sku( );
            $nc=$mydb->get_results("select cjenik_cijena from wp_cjenik_kupca WHERE (sifra_kupca ='$sifrovani' AND sifra_artikla='$sifbaza')");
             foreach ($nc as $objs2) {
              $novacen=$objs2->cjenik_cijena;
              }
            if (!($novacen==NULL))
               {
                 $konacnoprice=$novacen;
                 $rabat2=$mydb->get_results("select cjenik_rabat from wp_cjenik_kupca WHERE (sifra_kupca ='$sifrovani' AND sifra_artikla='$sifbaza')  ");
            foreach ($rabat2 as $objs5) {
              $konacnorabat=$objs5->cjenik_rabat;
              }
               }
             else  {
                  $konacnoprice=$productd->price;
                  $rabat3=$mydb->get_results("select cjenik_rabat from wp_cjenik_kupca WHERE (sifra_kupca ='$sifrovani' AND grupa_artikala='$cata')  ");
            foreach ($rabat3 as $objs5) {
              $konacnirabat=$objs5->cjenik_rabat;
              }
               }

             if (!($konacnirabat==NULL))
               {$price='5000';return $price;
                 exit;}
             else {$price=(intval($konacnoprice)-((intval($konacnorabat)/100)*intval($konacnoprice)));}
                 return $price;
                 exit;
          } 
}
`
```

Now i have problem in one case :

```
`if (!($konacnirabat==NULL))
               {$price='5000';return $price;
                 exit;}`
```

So all the prices are correctly changed on shop page, but when i Add to Cart specific product where field $konacnirabat is not null , it gives me wrong price result in cart.

Here are also screenshots with database tables needed for this :
[LINK](http://postimg.org/gallery/ft81keic/)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in last few days and I have found solution - you should use different filters - one when product is adding to cart and one when price is getting from cart session. Here is where I found answer: [source](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/4135)

Comment: I changed some parameters in my code and it works ! But there is a problem  now - this works only in local host (xamp). When i migrated my website to live hosting, shop page displays correct price ONLY FOR FIRST product in shop.when added to card,good price is added.